# form dictionary with same key for multiple values parse the xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, dictionary

MY xml format is this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?> 
<root>
<key value="22.wav">
<Index>18</Index>
</key>
<key value="EFG.wav">
<Index>5</Index>
<Index>14</Index>
</key>
</root>
```

How Do i form dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a how you parse the xml file and populate a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> keyIndexCollection = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("input.xml");
XmlNodeList keyNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("root/key");
List<int> indexValues = new List<int>();
foreach (XmlNode node in keyNodeList)
{
    XmlNodeList indexNodeList = node.SelectNodes("Index");
    int parsedIndex;
    indexValues.Clear();
    foreach (XmlNode indexNode in indexNodeList)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(indexNode.InnerText, out parsedIndex))
        {
            indexValues.Add(parsedIndex);
        }
    }

    keyIndexCollection.Add(node.Attributes["value"].Value, indexValues.ToArray());
}
```

and here is a sample code for iterating the dictionary

```
foreach (string key in keyIndexCollection.Keys)
{
    int[] values = keyIndexCollection[key];

    Console.WriteLine("Key = " + key);
    foreach (int value in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tValue = " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i parse and form dictionary dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
Dictionary<string, int[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
foreach (var key in doc.Root.Elements("key"))
{
    dictionary.Add((string)key.Attribute("value"), key.Elements("Index").Select(o => int.Parse((string)o)).ToArray());
}
```

Or simplified using `.ToDictionary()` extension method :

```
var dict = doc.Root
              .Elements("key")
              .ToDictionary(o => (string) o,
                            p => p.Elements("Index").Select(o => int.Parse((string) o)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load your XML like this:

```
var xd = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
```

Then you can create two different dictionaries like this:

```
var dict1 = 
    xd
        .Document
        .Root
        .Elements("key")
        .ToDictionary(
            x => x.Attribute("value").Value,
            x => x.Elements("Index")
                .Select(y => y.Value)
                .ToArray());


    var dict2 = 
    xd
        .Document
        .Root
        .Elements("key")
        .SelectMany(x => x
            .Elements("Index")
            .Select(y => new { x = x.Attribute("value").Value, y = y.Value }))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.y, x => x.x);
```

And these results look like this:

[image: Results]

I suspect you want the first one.

Comment: i want first one.thanks.And how do i comapre values of dictionary with single value.in dict1

Comment: IF i want to use dict1.containsValue(2) means it shows error cannot convert int[]  to int.how do i get values of single key

Comment: @munisamy - Try `dict1.Any(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(2))`.

Comment: thanks one more question how do i get value of dict1's efg.wav's  14 value

Comment: how do i check both key and value

Comment: @munisamy - Are you asking me how to check for existence of a key in a dictionary?

Comment: i have observable collection with this dict1's key,value and another one score what i will try to is compare dict1 and observablecollection if key and value is same as observable collection means needs to select score.for key it works correctly but for values it takes 22.wav values and efg.wav values i want only 22.wav's score var jj = from f in Afs
                     from s in f.segments
where (dict1.Any(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f.filename))) && dict1.Any(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains((s.sname.Split(Separators, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]))))select new { s.Conf };'

Comment: @munisamy - Try this: `var jj = from f in Afs from s in f.segments let fn = Path.GetFileName(f.filename) where dict1.ContainsKey(fn) let value = s.sname.Split(Separators, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] where dict1[fn].Contains(value) select s.Conf;`.